# What are precisely computational effects?

Tags: terminology

I'm really confused with definition of computational effects. What I knew and understood about computational effect were only that they're impure computation, but someone noticed me that computational effects includes continuation which doesn't seems to be impure. please someone reason these things.

Sorry for babbling, here is my actual questions:

1. What is formal(or at least precise) definition of computational effects?
2. If computational effects are impure things, then why continuation is included? is continuation impure?

Thx.

Comment: Here is a good definition with examples https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_system

Comment: well also, actually 
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/Overview.pdf

Comment: I've already read those articles briefly, and I couldn't find any detailed definition / explanation. Could you quote me the definition?

Comment: In my Haskell-centric experience, a _computational effect_ is "anything that can be crammed into the structure of a monad, applicative functor, arrow, etc.", and an _effect system_ is "any attempt at allowing computational effects to be combined in ways which are not permitted by monad transformers".

Comment: @AaronRotenberg That is because Haskell has adopted monad to be able to express computational effects following Moggi's work.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle

here is what I understood so far:

- **Computational effect**: which is expressed by effect system(which is used to be monad in Haskell)

- **Effect system**: what extends type system to add notion of computational effects by adding **effect kind** and **region** to type.

Am I right? or Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. The core idea is that continuations, side effects, non-determinism, etc, are all just instances of effect systems. Now, to give this notion of effect system a mathematical foundation Plotkin, Powers and others tried to use Lawvere theories. It works in some cases it doesn’t work in others esp. when you try to combine different effect systems together in one system.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle I was making a point that the things that get called _effects_ do not necessarily correspond to any sort of intuitive notion of "computational side effect", but rather it seems like what qualifies as an _effect_ is defined as whatever can be described using abstractions that generalize things that are considered to obviously count as _effects_.